# Why my ArrayField(models.ImageField()) is always getting null value?

Tags: django

I am trying to create an article with multiple images,but i am facing with a problem.

```
class Article(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    MediaImageArray = ArrayField(models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True),size=8,null=True)
```

When i am posting list of images named as `p1.jpg , p2.png`,it is always returning null like this:

**Using Postman:**

```
{
    "id": "34d75f5e-bd82-45a1-9c86-10e3f260311d",
    "author": "d39d29c8-4807-41c5-a3fa-e9cb117fdb2d",
    "MediaImageArray": [
        null,
        null
    ],
}
```

Does anybody know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayField` is not compatible to store images (even files, I think). Use reverse foreign key instead.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='articles')
    

class ArticleImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',null=True,blank=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```